# Datagrampacket to xml

Tags: xml, android, packet, datagram

Im trying to parse a Soap ProbeMatch message with XMLPullParser. I receive this via UDP Multicast. I use the following code to receive it.

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1900];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

mSocket.receive(packet);

// Damn ugly....
String data = new String(packet.getData())
```

If i convert the byte[] to String the Parser doesnt eat it... Are there any more elegant ways to do this?

When i print the xml (as String), i get the unused bytes at the end of the String:

```
</s12:Envelope>À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?À?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I think you'll want to construct the String as follows:

```
String data = new String(packet.getData(), 
                         packet.getOffset(), 
                         packet.getLength());
```

As to there being a better way. AIUI not really, though there might be a third party API out there that makes filling/emptying the datagrams a bit easier, as all the byte packing is very fiddly.